# Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is a non-zero symmetric zero-diagonal matrix and its elements are $0$ ore $1$. What we can say about eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is a non-zero symmetric zero-diagonal matrix and its elements are $0$ ore $1$. We know that the eigenvalue of $A$ are real. I'm interesting to know the number of distinct eigenvlue of the matrix $A$. How many of them are greater than $1$ and how many of them are lower than $1$?
Since $\mathrm{trac}(A)=0$, we get that some eigenvalue of $A$ is negative and some of them are positive. In the case that $A=[a_{ij}]$ and $\Pi_{i\ne j}a_{ij}=1$ (i.e. $a_{ij}=1$ for $i\ne j$ and $a_{ii}=0$) the answer is easy and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=n-1$ by repeated order $1$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ by repeated order $n-1$. My question is about the case that: $\Pi_{i\ne j}a_{ij}=0$ (i.e. there is $i\ne j$ which $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=0$).

Comment: What's a "zero-diagonal matrix"?

Comment: It's mean the diagonal elements of $A$ are $0$.

Comment: I think that it's a major problem in spectral graph theory

Comment: @Exodd: Can you give me a refrence to finding the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, it has some connection with the graph theory, since a binary symmetric matrix with zero diagonal is the adjacency matrix of a graph.

For example, the matrix with all the elements equal to 1 (except for the diagonal) is the adjacency matrix of the complete graph with $n$ nodes, and it is known that

> a binary matrix $A$ with zero diagonal has exactly two distinct eigenvalues if and only if it is the the adjacency matrix of the complete graph

An other curiosity is for example that

> a binary matrix $A$ with zero diagonal has the spectrum symmetric (that is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue) if and only if it is the the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph

Regarding the number of distinct eigenvalue, we know an inferior bound in particular situation: Let's say that a graph $G$ is regular if every node has the same degree, and let's call $d(G)$ the [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory))

> Given a regular graph $G$, then $d(G)$ is always strictly less then the number of distinct eigenvalues of its adjacency matrix

Comment: Thank you for your help but i'm not familiar with the graph theory. Can you introduce to me some good refrence please?

Comment: All I know about this matter comes from articles I read for my degree, so I'm not the right person to suggest a book. Just try to look for "spectral graph theory" book.

Answer (score 2):

There is basically nothing that can be said. For instance, if 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&\cdots&1\\ 1&0&0&\cdots&0\\ \vdots &\vdots&\ddots \\
1&0&0&\cdots&0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the eigenvalues are $\sqrt{n-1}$ and $-\sqrt{n-1}$ each with multiplicity one, and $0$ with multiplicity $n-2$. Or, if 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\  1&0&1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots &\vdots&&&\ddots \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(i.e., $A_{ij}=1$ if $i=j\pm1$), then the eigenvalues are 
$$
2\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1},\ \ k=1,2,\ldots,n.
$$

Comment: in your first example, you have the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-2$, and the simple eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{n-1}$

Comment: @Exodd: thanks for noticing; I mixed up with another example.

Comment: @Hamid: those examples (and combinations of them) show that you can have almost any mixture of positive and negatives and zeroes.

Comment: Adding the answers, we can also use [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_inequality) to see that, once $A$ is diagonalizable, the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ satisfy $\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\leq \sqrt{n^n}$.